# How do I disable (only) the following Sphinx autodocs warning? "WARNING: duplicate object description of .."

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

this warning is dumping lots of unwanted and misguided noise at me:

https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/35965903177c6ed9a6afb62ccd33243a746a3fc0/sphinx/domains/python.py#L1520

how can I get rid of it? and only this specific warning? without forking sphinx?

Comment: `make docs >/dev/null 2>&1` works, which is great, because it calms me down not being flooded with useless (ultimately misguided) noise, but I'd prefer to still see actual useful information if possible (that is warnings _other_ than the one in the title).